# Why does string.replace(/\W*/g,'_') prepend all characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been learning regexp in js an encountered a situation that I didn't understand.

I ran a test of the replace function with the following regexp:

```
/\W*/g
```

And expected it prepend the beginning of the string and proceed to replace all non-word characters.

```
The Number is (123)(234)
```

would become:

```
_The_Number_is__123___234_
```

This would be prepending the string because it has at least zero instances, and then replacing all non-breaking spaces and non-word characters.

Instead, it prepended every character and replaced all non-word characters.

```
_T_h_e__N_u_m_b_e_r__i_s__1_2_3__2_3_4__
```

Why did it do this?

Comment: Why do you expect `_` at the start of the string? If you fix the regex and use `/\W/g` you would get `The_Number_is__123__234_`. Isn't that the expected result?

Comment: Since I used `*` I assumed that it would start with an underscore since there will automatically be at least zero instances of non-word characters.

Comment: So, what are the actual requirements?

Comment: Ok, you need `.replace(/\W|^/g, '_')` then

Comment: Thanks for the working answer. It looks like you are matching start of input and then a global search for all non-word characters.

I think I just didn't understand the mechanics of how the search is conducted.

When a match is found, the replace function does a replacement and then moves to the next character, starting the search over. Right?

Comment: It moves to the next char if the pattern is all consuming. It is even more complicated with zero-width matches and `.replace(/\W|^/g, '_')` will not work if `"+Word"` should be turned into `"__Word"`.

Comment: That's interesting.

Comment: I added some more details to the answer. I hope you will find them interesting, too.

Comment: If you let it match _nothing_ with the `*` it will match every spot that is a word character as well as matching 1 or more non-word characters. Beware of this scenario. And, btw, this is nothing unique to JS, all engines would do this...

Comment: Is this _expected_ ? `The Number is (123)(234)` would become `_The_Number_is__123___234_` There is a typo there. It would become `_The_Number_is__123__234_` If the `___` is somehow _expected_ then you'd need a more involved regex that is more specific to some parenthesis.

Comment: I noticed that @sln. You're right that it would take singling out the parenthases and preppending an underscore on their replacement to get this (and still there would be a typo at the end of the string).

The reason that I didn't take it out is that I didn't have a clear understanding of the way the regexp works at all.

Ultimately, WiktorStribiżew was especially effective in setting me straight.

If you think it would be more appropriate for me to fix my expectation so that it is a more accurate question, I would be glad to do it.

Comment: @JuddFranklin - It's not a straight forward explanation what steps some engines take to optimize expressions. If you're new to regex, the subject is over your head right now. Maybe in the future.

Comment: @sln - Yes, I'm just getting started. It looks like you are strong in regex. Any suggested resources for deepening my knowledge are always appreciated. Otherwise, its just time and exploration, which is fine.

Comment: @JuddFranklin - The only resource I know is myself. All of my 1600 regex posts and 5000 comments about regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> 1. **Never use a pattern that can match an empty string in a regex replace method if your aim is to replace and not insert text**
> 2. To replace all separate occurrences of a non-word char in a string, use `.replace(/\W/g, '_')` (that is, remove `*` quantifier that matches zero or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern)
> 3. To replace all **chunks of** non-word chars in a string with a single pattern, use `.replace(/\W+/g, '_')` (that is, replace `*` quantifier with `+` that matches *one or more* occurrences of the quantified subpattern)
>      
>    **Note:** the solution below is tailored for the OP much more specific requirements.

A string is parsed by the JS regex engine as a sequence of chars and *locations in between them*. See the following diagram where I marked locations with hyphens:

```
  -T-h-e- -N-u-m-b-e-r- -i-s- -(-1-2-3-)-(-2-3-4-)-
  |||                                             |
  ||Location between T and h, etc. .............  |
  |1st symbol                                     |
start                     ->                     end
```

All these positions can be analyzed and *matched* with a regex.

Since `/\W*/g` is a regex matching all non-overlapping occurrences (due to `g` modifier) of **0 and more** (due to `*` quantifier) non-word chars, **all the positions before word chars are matched**. Between `T` and `h`, there is a location tested with the regex, and as there is no non-word char (`h` is a word char), the empty match is returned (as `\W*` can match an empty string).

So, you need to replace the start of string and each non-word char with a `_`. Naive approach is to use `.replace(/\W|^/g, '_')`. However, there is a caveat: if a string starts with a non-word character, no `_` will get appended at the start of the string:

```js
console.log("Hi there.".replace(/\W|^/g, '_'));  // _Hi_there_
console.log(" Hi there.".replace(/\W|^/g, '_')); // _Hi_there_
```

Note that here, `\W` comes first in the alternation and "wins" when matching at the beginning of the string: the space is matched and then no start position is found at the next match iteration.

You may now think you can match with `/^|\W/g`. Look here:

```js
console.log("Hi there.".replace(/^|\W/g, '_'));  // _Hi_there_
console.log(" Hi there.".replace(/^|\W/g, '_')); // _ Hi_there_
```

The `_ Hi_there_` second result shows *how JS regex engine handles zero-width matches during a replace operation*: once a zero-width match (here, it is the position at the start of the string) is found, the replacement occurs, and the `RegExp.lastIndex` property is incremented, thus proceeding to the position after the first character! That is why the first space is preserved, and no longer matched with `\W`.

A solution is to use a *consuming* pattern that will not allow zero-width matches:

```js
console.log("Hi there.".replace(/^(\W?)|\W/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? "__" : "_"; }));
console.log(" Hi there.".replace(/^(\W?)|\W/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? "__" : "_"; }));
```

Comment: Can you share links to specifications, references to further details as to _"locations"_ portion of Answer.

Comment: @guest271314: Have a look at [What is a Regex?](http://rexegg.com/): *"Those text strings describe patterns to find text or positions within a body of text. For instance, the regex foo matches the string foo, the regex `[A-Z]+:\d+` matches string fragments like `F:1` and `GO:30`, and the regex `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` matches the position in the string `CamelCase` where we shift from a lower-case letter to an upper-case letter."*. There are hints at that in [First Look at How a Regex Engine Works Internally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html).

Comment: Thanks for the resource @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: `shows how JS regex engine handles zero-width matches` - This is not unique to JS regex, it's with all engines ...

Comment: @sln: Engines differ: [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/bJfPgL/1) handles the same situation  well, unlike [JS](https://regex101.com/r/bJfPgL/2).

Comment: Yet, PCRE is still like the others. A special Perl/PCRE optimization / 1-time do-over.   https://regex101.com/r/bJfPgL/4

Answer (score 9):

The problem is the meaning of `\W*`. It means "0 or more non-word characters". This means that the empty string `""` would match, given that it is indeed 0 non-word characters.

So the regex matches before every character in the string and at the end, hence why all the replacements are done.

You want either `/\W/g` (replacing each individual non-word character) or `/\W+/g` (replacing each set of consecutive non-word characters).

```
"The Number is (123)(234)".replace(/\W/g, '_')  // "The_Number_is__123__234_"
"The Number is (123)(234)".replace(/\W+/g, '_') // "The_Number_is_123_234_"
```

Comment: Neither of the solutions return the expected `_The_Number_is__123___234_`

Comment: I see that my expectation was wrong, but I think that it has something to do with how the regexp returns multiple results. Like it starts its search over as soon as it finds a result.

Comment: I do like your explanation @lonesomeday. I would have upvoted it if I had the reputation to do so. I'll come back and do that when I reach enough points.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/(^\W*){1}|\W(?!=\w)/g` to match one `\W` at beginning of string or `\W` not followed by `\w`

```js
var str = "The Number is (123)(234)";
var res = str.replace(/(^\W*){1}|\W(?!=\w)/g, "_");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I see that this works. But why does the other one have the unexpected result?

Comment: @JuddFranklin _"\W 
Matches any character that is not a word character from the basic Latin alphabet. "_ ,  _"x* 
Matches the preceding item x 0 or more times."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp . For example, `"abc".split("") // ["a", "b", "c"]` @WiktorStribiżew Answer describes the result far more accurately than presently able to here.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used /\W+/g instead.

"*" means all characters by itself.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if I could also get a character prepended on the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the `*` operator. That matches **zero** or more characters. So between every character matches. If you replace the expression with `/\W+/g` it works as you expected.

Comment: My question is why does between every character match? Does the search seek zero or more instances again after it finds the first match?

Comment: @JuddFranklin Yes that's what the `/g` flag means. Search *globally*.

Comment: I think I didn't understand how the regexp engine conducts its global search, whether after the first result it discards the search for the zeroth result, or if it keeps that caveat.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

Find:  `(?=.)(?:^\W|\W$|\W|^|(.)$)`
Replace: `$1_`

Cases explained:

```
 (?= . )       # Must be at least 1 char
 (?:           # Ordered Cases:
      ^ \W          # BOS + non-word (consumes bos)
   |  \W $          # Non-word + EOS (consumes eos)
   |  \W            # Non-word
   |  ^             # BOS
   |  ( . )         # (1), Any char + EOS
      $ 
 )
```

Note this could have been done without the lookahead via
`(?:^\W|\W$|\W|^$)`

But, this will insert a single `_` on an empty string.
So, it ends up being more elaborate.
All in all though, it's a simple replacement.
Unlike Stribnez's solution, no callback logic is required
on the replace side.